# NestJS: UseGuards Doesn't Use Dependency Injection - Can't Override Guard

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, inversion-of-control

### Current behavior

The documentation states [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#binding-guards) that:

> ...we passed the RolesGuard type (instead of an instance), leaving responsibility for instantiation to the framework and enabling dependency injection.

So I'm expecting to "override" a guard with another, via the module's `providers`.
This doesn't work as expected.

Interestingly enough,
injecting the same service via the controller's constructor does yield the correct service, though.

### Input Code

Simple: https://github.com/dima-gusyatiner/nestjs-guards-override/tree/only-app-module

With Another module, using `exports`: https://github.com/dima-gusyatiner/nestjs-guards-override/tree/master

Controller:

```
@Controller()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
```

Module:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthGuard,
      useClass: AuthOverrideGuard,
    }
  ],
})
```

### Expected behavior

I would expect `AuthGuard` to never even be constructed.
Instead, both classes are constructed, and `AuthGuard` is used as the guard.

### Environment

```
- Nest version: 8.0.6
- Node version: 16.8.0
- Platform: Linux
```

### Bug Report

I've also opened a ticket for this:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8011

### Question

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug?
Anybody can suggest a workaround?

Comment: It's pretty interesting case I have to say. 
Anyway, can you explain why you need it? It looks like you're doing something wrong if you need it (even if it's a bug)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand it that well either but from what I saw:

- With UseGuards, the passed in class is not resolved as provider. Only when you declare the guard as a dependency. Just like in AppController, is it looked up in the provider scope.
- Sure the guard's dependencies are resolved as providers within the calling module's scope but it itself is not. Just regular instantiation with dependency injection.
- I think that is why both guards are still created, just that AuthOverrideGuard, is registered as a provider.

That is why you get the following output:

```sh
[Nest] 77074  - 05/09/2021, 05:01:39     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
Construct AuthOverrideGuard
Construct AuthGuard
AuthGuard
AppController AuthOverrideGuard {}
```

- This is why this.guard is correctly resolved as AuthOverrideGuard from the provider scope

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, in my understanding, **the docs are inaccurate**.

The documentation states [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#binding-guards) that:

> ...we passed the RolesGuard type (instead of an instance), leaving responsibility for instantiation to the framework ***and enabling dependency injection***.

This is inaccurate, since `RolesGuard` won't be instantiated with proper dependency injection. Instead, it will be instantiated using **this exact class only**.

To achieve proper dependency injection, one should use another class, injected via the guard's constructor. For example:

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthService } from '../services';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly auth: AuthService,
    ) {}

    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        return this.auth.canActivate(context);
    }
}
```

You can never provide another `AuthGuard`, it won't work. But you can provide another `AuthService`, which this guard uses.

```
@Module({
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthService,
      useClass: AuthServiceOverride,
    }
  ],
})
```